# Cleanup all c++ objects after python script is finished

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have an application, implementing python interpreter, with custom python modules, exporting classes. Example c++ class may look like:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass() { cout << "created" << endl; }
    ~MyClass() { cout << "destroyed" << endl; }
};
```

Code for executing python scripts looks like:

```
namespace bp = boost::python;
bp::dict dict;

try {
    dict = bp::dict(bp::import("__main__").attr("__dict__"));
    bp::exec_file(filename, dict, dict);
} catch (bp::error_already_set &) {
    // dict.clear()
    PyErr_Print();
    PyErr_Clear();
}
```

The issue is, c++ objects created from python code are not destroyed immediately after script is terminated by exception. For example, simple script is run twice:

```
import MyModule
myobj = MyModule.MyClass()
assert False
```

output I get (**A**):

```
// script launched first time
created
// script finished
// script launched second time
created
destroyed
// script finished
// Py_Finalize() is called
destroyed
```

output I want (**B**):

```
// script launched first time
created
// script finished
destroyed
// script launched second time
created
// script finished
destroyed
// Py_Finalize() is called
```

Now, the fun part. If we uncomment `// dict.clear()`, behavior starts being different depending on script structure. For the abovementioned python snippet I get output **B** (as expected), but I still get **A** for script like:

```
import MyModule

def main():
    myobj = MyModule.MyClass()
    assert False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How to properly delete c++ objects, created from python?

Comment: Consider using Python's *Context Manager*, i.e. the `with` statement thing.

Comment: @NickyC, thing is, there have to be no restrictions for python scripts. Just interpreter, running them, and restoring application state afterwards.

Comment: Dunno if it would be practical for your use case, but you could have your MyClass constructor the MyClass object (this) to a static/global linked-list, and the MyClass destructor remove (this) from the linked-list.  Then, after your Python script has exited, your C++ code could iterate over that linked-list and delete any MyClass objects that remain in the list.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, python takes full ownership of c++ objects. Adding them into list will either just store copies (not what I want) or store reference-counted pointer copies (will not delete them). Attempt to delete objects directly, bypassing python API, will end up with crash.

Comment: What @NickyC is saying, is if you want deterministic release of a resource, you need to use the language construct that provides deterministic release of resources. The semantics of C++ are like *every value* is created in a `with` context

Comment: Also output B looks suspect. How is the second `MyClass` meant to be constructed if what it is copied from is already destroyed?

Comment: @Caleth, I want this deterministic release of resources to be done from c++ code. Secondly, `MyClass` instances are not copied.

Comment: Then why is there two pairs of "created" "destroyed" in the output? There is an implicit copy occurring

Comment: @Caleth, as I mentioned, script is run twice before program termination. It is meant to make things a bit easier to understand

Comment: are you repeating `bp::exec_file(filename, dict, dict);` to run the script twice? That looks like a smoking gun. You probably need to dispose of the contents of dict between runs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161603/discussion-between-andrei-r-and-caleth).

Answer (score 1):

You can give ownership of c++ object to python.
Please check below example, it might work for you.
Also check the [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation/models_of_callpolicies.html) link for more understanding of call policies.

C++ code:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
    MyClass() { cout << "created" << endl; }
    ~MyClass() { cout << "destroyed" << endl; }
};

MyClass* get_objectof_MyClass(){

    return new MyClass();
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MyModule)
{   
    class_<MyClass>("MyClass");

    def("get_objectof_MyClass", get_objectof_MyClass, return_value_policy<manage_new_object>());
    //using manage_new_object we are giving ownership to python side and python will clean it up when out of scope.
}
```

Python side code:

```
import MyModule

def main():
    myobj = MyModule.get_objectof_MyClass()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
created
destroyed
```